# How to report cell value to another cell on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm entering datas in A column of a table. According to the datas, I making sums from the yellow cell (actually this yellow cell is the high value of the A column). So all 10 cells, there is a sum until the end of datas.

I'm looking for automatically report the seven first grey cells (the sums)to another table. The problem is, according to the datas, high value is not at the same place so the sums are not to the same place too.

[image]

[image]

How can I do ?

Thank you for your help

MY ERROR :

[image]

And the message when I press ctrl maj enter in same time :

[image]

Comment: Are you creating the sums automatically? And how? What's the formula or logic? Where do you need the report? On the same sheet (as per your sample) or on another sheet?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes on the same sheet.
my formula for sums is : 

`SI(OU(LIGNE(E4)<EQUIV(GRANDE.VALEUR($E$4:$E$117;1);$E$4:$E$117;0)+LIGNE($E$4);MOD(LIGNE(E4)−(EQUIV(GRANDE.VALEUR($E$4:$E$117;1);$E$4:$E$117;0)+LIGNE($E$4));10)>0);"";SOMME(DECALER($E$4;(EQUIV(GRANDE.VALEUR($E$4:$E$117;1);$E$4:$E$117;0))+((LIGNE(E4)−(EQUIV(GRANDE.VALEUR($E$4:$E$117;1);$E$4:$E$117;0)+LIGNE($E$4))));;10)))`

Comment: Have you considered using the formula in the report and another formula to write the results into your list?

Comment: sorry I clicked on "enter" too quickly xD

Comment: The table on my sample is just below the data table on the same sheet. So I have to report the sums on the same column but on another row

Comment: I didn't understand what you suggest. I don't know at all excel. Somebody helped me for the formula...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find a solution to report the values from `F` to another table. As values positions are dependant  of the `MAX` raw in `E` (every 10 cells) I make this formula :

For the first : `INDEX(E4:F117;EQUIV(GRANDE.VALEUR($E$4:$E$117;1);$E$4:$E$117;0)+10;2)`

For the second : 
`INDEX(E4:F117;EQUIV(GRANDE.VALEUR($E$4:$E$117;1);$E$4:$E$117;0)+20;2)`

Etc...

Answer (score 1):

You might use this array formula in your report.

```
=INDEX($F:$F,SMALL(ROW($F$4:$F$117)+(100*(F$4:$F$117="")), ROW(F1)))&""
```

Bear in mind that, as an array formula, it must be confirmed with Control+Shift+Enter. Enter the formula in the row where you have Somme = 1, then copy down  to 6. Note that `Row(F1)` is a counter. You have a similar counter (1 to 6) in F124:F130. Therefore you can replace `ROW(F1)` with `$F124` (if that is where the "1" is) to make it easier to understand, perhaps.

The formula retrieves the value of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc non-blank cell in the range F4:F117. If those cells contain a formula they will be considered "blank" if their result equals "".

BTW, if you don't always have 113 results to evaluate you might consider giving a name to the range E4:E117. For example, if you name that range as "Results" then =SUM(Results) would be the same as =SUM($E$4:$E$117), but as you insert or delete rows within the named range the formula doesn't need to be amended. Use of a named range would simplify understanding your existing formula. You could do the same with column F.

Comment: It doesn't work. "the formula contains a invalid reference."
My soft is in french so I replace "," by ";"

Comment: Could it be a translation problem? I tested with Excel 2010 (earlier than 2007 might be different). Make sure there are no merged cells in column F (or the column you specified instead of $F:$F. Ensure that your equivalent of `ROW(F1)` and up to `ROW(F6)` doesn't specify a merged cell. Test replacing `ROW(F1)` with a hard number, like 1 or 3. Finally, test the formula on a blank sheet where F4:F117 has no formulas, just a few random values. However, I don't think it is your existing formula that is causing a problem.

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot. But without that change you made it should have worked even less. :-) Please check the function names here: http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-french.html

Comment: There are merged cells . I tried with blank sheet and it doesn't work too. I already used a function name translation to be sure. So I don't know where is the problem... I don't know what I have to do

Comment: Show me the adapted function which doesn't work on your blank sheet. I will try to "reverse engineer" it, see if I can make it fail for me. Make sure there are no merged cells in your blank sheet, that the formula is not in a range referenced by it, and that the error is "formula contains invalid reference" (not #NUM, for example). Do you understand the meaning of "confirm with Shift+Ctl+Enter"? When entered correctly you should see the formula surrounded by curly braces in the formula bar. Unfortunately, I won't be able to get back to you until tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Haox, the French formula you can try is this: `=INDEX($F:$F;PETITE.VALEUR(LIGNE($F$4:$F$57)+(100*(F$4:$F$57=""));LIGNE(F1)))&""`.  Remember this is an array formula.

Comment: that's exactly what I have

Comment: Your formula wasn't entered as an array formula. To correct the entry, make any insignificant change to the formula (like replacing 1 with 01), or enter it completely new, then hold down a Shift key and the Control key and press Enter (all three keys down at the same time). When you do this correctly the formula will appear as `{=INDEX($F:$F;PETITE.VALEUR(LIGNE($F$4:$F$57)+(100*(F$4:$F$57‌​=""));LIGNE(F1)))&""‌​}` - between curly braces - in the formula bar.